# How can I rewrite these 2 views to 1 view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I rewrite these 2 views to 1 view?

**serializers**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):​
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'ip_address',
        ]
​
​
class StatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
        fields = ['clicks', 'page_views', 'date']
​
​
class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    max_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    min_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ...
        return data
```

**views​**

```
class UserListApiView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    pagination_class = UsersSetPagination
​
​
class StatisticAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserStatisticSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=GENDER_MALE)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']


class Statistic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statistics')
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    page_views = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    clicks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Comment: What is the definition of  the `Statistic` model?

Comment: @RossRogers updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Override your `APIViews` to `GenericAPIView` with `ModelMixins` and override `get_serializer_class` using `action`

```
class UsersAPIView(ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    pagination_class = UsersSetPagination

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            serializer = UserSerializer
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            serializer = UserStatisticSerializer
        return serializer
```

2. Register this endpoints in `urls`

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'', UsersAPIView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you defined your `UserStatisticSerializer` like this, you'd acheive your goal:

```
class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()      # not sure on these fields
    max_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  # not sure on these fields
    min_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  # not sure on these fields


    statistics = StatisticSerializer(many=True) # <---

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'ip_address',
                'statistics' # <---
            ]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that’s not what I need. Serializers are right. They do not need to be touched.
I just want to rewrite the __two views to one__, if possible. They differ only in base classes and serializers.